# How to produce well formatted tables

Tags: tables

I want to produce a table with no vertical lines and I used the following code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Annualized Sharpe ratios for the mean reversion strategies.}\label{tab:1}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.1in} p{0.5in} p{0.6in} p{0.4in} p{0.3in} p{0.5in}} 
        ~ & \textbf{CMSTNO  } & \textbf{RS-CMSTNO} & \textbf{HRP} & \textbf{MSR} & \textbf{S\&P500} \\ 
        Annualized mean & 16.47\% & 17.43\% & 8.72\% & 7.18\% & 11.38\% \\  
        Annualized st. deviation & 12.93\% & 12.70\% & 10.46\% & 8.78\% & 16.44\% \\  
        Skewness & -1.46 & -1.46 & -1.41 & -0.62 & -0.94 \\  
        Kurtosis & 5.53 & 5.27 & 7.76 & 4.07 & 8.01 \\  
        Volatility Skewness & 0.92 & 0.87 & 0.83 & 1.08 & 0.95 \\  
        Sharpe Ratio & 1.3 & 1.42 & 0.8 & 0.8 & 0.64 \\  
        Sortino Ratio & 0.24 & 0.26 & 0.16 & 0.162 & 0.133 \\  
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Nevertheless, some column names end up one of on top of the other (column name 1 and 2 in particular) and also the name of the second row, Annualized st. deviation, is printed on two rows.

Any idea on how to not have the row names printed on two rows/column names printed on top of each other?

Many thanks.

Comment: `p` colums are for paragraphs that can linebreak to the specified width you want the columns here to be the natural width of the data so `r` or better D (from `dcolumn` or `S` (from `siunitx`) so the numeric data aligns on the decimal point.  Please provide the code as a small but complete document so we can run it, eg `[H]` option is not defined by default, and we have no idea how wide your column is to fit the table.

Comment: You indirectly answered my question, pointing me to the width of the column in inches. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also use horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Changes in comparison to the original:

- `l` type column instead of `p` for the first column to prevent linebreaks
- `S` type columns form `siunitx` to improve alignment of numbers in their columns
- horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` for improved spacing around the horizontal lines
- `caption` package for improved spacing between caption and table
- `tabular*` in combination with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` and `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`  in order to make sure the table fits into the textwidth. (Probably net needed, depends on the documentclass/ available space)
- removed bold in column headers to save space
- abbreviated entry in the first column to save space
- removed repeated `\%` and added this information into the first column instead in order to avoid repetition/ save space.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Annualized Sharpe ratios for the mean reversion strategies.}\label{tab:1}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{3}{S[table-format=-2.2]} *{2}{S[table-format=-2.3]}}
    \toprule 
                                 & {CMSTNO} & {RS-CMSTNO} & {HRP} & {MSR} & {S\&P500} \\ 
         \midrule
        Annualized mean (\%)     & 16.47    & 17.43       & 8.72  & 7.18  & 11.38     \\  
        Annualized st. dev. (\%) & 12.93    & 12.70       & 10.46 & 8.78  & 16.44     \\  
        Skewness                 & -1.46    & -1.46       & -1.41 & -0.62 & -0.94     \\  
        Kurtosis                 & 5.53     & 5.27        & 7.76  & 4.07  & 8.01      \\  
        Volatility Skewness      & 0.92     & 0.87        & 0.83  & 1.08  & 0.95      \\  
        Sharpe Ratio             & 1.3      & 1.42        & 0.8   & 0.8   & 0.64      \\  
        Sortino Ratio            & 0.24     & 0.26        & 0.16  & 0.162 & 0.133     \\  
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```